# WCF Data Services, Entity Framework and Spatial Types

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services, spatial

So back in June 2011, Microsoft released a CTP adding support for spatial types to the Entity Framework.  Then in October 2011, the released a CTP adding support for spatial tyes to WCF Data Services.  However, you can't use the two together.  It was a big caveat in the WCF Data Services Oct 2011 CTP.

Has anyone heard when Microsoft plans on bridging this gap?  I'm sure it's coming eventually but obviously sooner would be better than later.

Comment: confirmed on MSDN forum - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nn-NO/adodotnetdataservices/thread/54bf62d7-2ed5-4992-b5a6-de8f301531b4

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a workarround about this. The solution is to define wrappers which define a common data model for both types. http://www.odata.org/case-study/how-to-use-sql-spatial-data-with-wcf-odata-spatial/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, references tend to get stale over time. Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.